# How to get Current htaccess directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have following strucuture

`/var/www` which is pointed by `localhost`
there is directory called `mytestsite` in it.

My rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/controllers/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?lang=en&module=$1 [L]
```

And that would work only:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mytestsite/controllers/$1\.php -f
```

I tried with `RewriteBase` but this seems not to change `%{DIRECTORY_ROOT}`

Is there any way to dynamically point/get current htaccess relative/absolute path for check? Tried many variations.

Comment: Is `var/www/mytestsite/controller s/file.php` the actual physical  location of your php files?

Comment: @starkeen Yes. it is. I have 1 site which where .htaccess  is in root domain and I start it like `domain.com/index.php/` and i have test enviroment `localhost/testenv/index.php`. Problem is, I need to have 2 different .htaccess for each site and my aim is to make one rule that would allow me to switch folders/subdirs